# How to calculate true positive rate?

Tags: r, machine-learning, roc

I have made model that predicts late arrival of flights.I want to see the true positive rate, given a false positive rate of 50%. I can see this in a ROC curve I plot. But I want to calculate the value exactly, not just reading it from the plot. Anyone has an idea how?

```
library(modelr)
library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(nycflights13)
data(flights)

RNGkind(sample.kind="Rounding")
set.seed(42)

flights <- mutate(flights, late_arrival = ifelse(arr_delay > 30, 1, 0))

spark_install()
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

flights_tbl <- copy_to(sc, flights, "flights")
flights_tbl <- flights_tbl %>% na.omit(flights_tbl)

partition <- flights_tbl %>% 
  select(late_arrival, carrier, dep_delay, month, year) %>%
  sdf_random_split(train = 0.75, test = 0.25)

train_tbl <- partition$train
test_tbl <- partition$test

########### my model
ml_formula <- formula(late_arrival ~ carrier + dep_delay + month + year)
ml_log <- ml_logistic_regression(train_tbl,ml_formula)
ml_log

pred_lr <- ml_predict(ml_log, test_tbl) %>% collect
pred_lr$p1 <- unlist(pred_lr$probability)[ c(FALSE,TRUE) ]

########## my ROC curve plot
ROC_lr <- get_roc(L = pred_lr$late_arrival, f = pred_lr$p1)
ggplot(ROC_lr, aes(x = FPR, y = TPR)) + geom_line(aes(col = "my prediction")) + ggtitle("ROC curve of my prediction", "logistic regression to predict late arrivals based on carrier, departure delay, month, and year")
```

Comment: Please don't cross post questions, it's poor etiquette. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473551/how-to-calculate-true-positive-rate-with-r

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure which forum fits better, I'm new here. I won't do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `get_roc()`, but you can certainly print out the `ROC_lr` to get some nearby values:

```
print(ROC_lr)
```

But you can try another package: package [`pROC`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pROC) has function [`coords()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.16.2/topics/coords) to count values from the ROC curve at some point:

```
library(pROC)

# only some random values for example
labels <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
scores <- 1:10

# instead of get_roc() you can use pROC::roc()
roc <- roc(labels, scores)

# let's say you want FPR 0.5 and calculate TPR
fpr <- 0.5

# coords() needs specificity (1 - FPR) to calculate sensitivity (TPR)
fpr50 <- coords(roc, 1 - fpr, input = "specificity")

# get TPR from the result
tpr <- fpr50$sensitivity

tpr
#[1] 0.6666667
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it that way. What are labels and scores in my case? I have flights that are actually late (1) or not (0). I also have, for each of these flights, a prediction if they were late or not (1/0). Would "labels" be the actual flight status 0/1 and "score" my prediction 0/1? I could also use the probability of my predictions.

Comment: @E_H The first argument will be late arrivales (0 or 1), second argument can be either probabilities (0.0 - 1.00), but you can use predictions (0 or 1) as well. If your machine learning model outputs probabilities, use probabilities, if it's output are predicted classes, use predicted classes. See documentation for more information (parameters, possibilities etc.).